# How I can reduce ember app build time on windows 10 but it works fine on ubuntu

Tags: ember.js

I want to reduce build time of ember app. It is taking quite a lot time to build app specifically on windows 10 while it works great on Ubuntu. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

These should make a difference:

- Install ember-cli-windows (see https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-windows)
- Exclude your ember project folder from your antivirus, Windows Defender, etc.
- Disable Search/Cortana from indexing your ember project folder

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your global ember-cli to 2.13 or more, glimmer will decrease build time for you. And install ember-cli-windows to get rid off all tmp files.
You can also manually delete tmp file from your workspace, that improves your application rebuild time.

Comment: I am using latest ember 3.0